# How to render an image in rails 4 that is not part of asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, asset-pipeline

I am working on a Rails 4 app.  In this app I have a bunch of "items" in my database.  Each item has an attribute "image", which is a string where I store some html which contains an html image tag that links to another site.  For example, a typical item has an image:

```
<a href=\"http://anotherpage.com\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"http://anotherpage.com/path/to/image\" ></a>
```

I render this image by calling:

```
<%= raw item.image %>
```

But I have certain cases, where I would like to render an image that is stored on my server.  In previous version of rails, I could just stick an image in public, and use an image tag like so:

```
<img src="image.jpg" />
```

But I can't figure out how to do this with the asset pipeline.  I know that I can do something like so:

```
<%= image_tag "image.jpg" %>
```

Or:

```
<img src="<%= asset_path('image.jpg') %>" />
```

But how could I store this in my database so that all I have to do to render it is:

```
<%= raw item.image %>
```

Is there a way that ruby code stored in my database, and output in a view can be interpreted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a directory: public/images, and put image.jpg into that directory.  I then rendered the image by calling:

```
<img src="/images/image.jpg" />
```

My original problem was that I had an image in public and called

```
<img src="image.jpg" />
```

I think that way would have worked if I just appended a forward slash to the image:

```
<img src="/image/jpg" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Prepend `/assets` to image path:

```
<img src="/assets/image.jpg">
```

Comment: This works in development, but it does not work in my production environment (I'm running on heroku)   I do have other images in my app that do utilize the asset pipeline.

Comment: Figured it out.  I made a directory "public/images", puts my image in there, and then referenced it by:

    <img src="/images/image.jpg" />

Comment: Nice! Thanks For The Followup.